# file_exists() expects parameter 1 to be a valid path, string given

Tags: php, docx

I have looked up on the site for an answer and I don't seem to be able to find a solution to my problem.

I have tried using this

```
$cleaned = strval(str_replace("\0", "", $string));
```

I have also tried:

- getcwd()
- dirname(**FILE**)
- basename(**DIR**)

however I always the the error `file_exists()` expects parameter 1 to be a valid path, string given in

however I can use `file_get_contents()` and it will open the document in that directory. however when I pass the docx file to be stripped to text it won't open the directory.

**Here is my code:**

```
class DocxConversion{
        private $filename;

        public function __construct($filePath) {
            $this->filename = $filePath;
        }

        private function read_doc() {
            $fileHandle = fopen($this->filename, "r");
            $line = @fread($fileHandle, filesize($this->filename));   
            $lines = explode(chr(0x0D),$line);
            $outtext = "";
            foreach($lines as $thisline)
              {
                $pos = strpos($thisline, chr(0x00));
                if (($pos !== FALSE)||(strlen($thisline)==0))
                  {
                  } else {
                    $outtext .= $thisline." ";
                  }
              }
             $outtext = preg_replace("/[^a-zA-Z0-9\s\,\.\-\n\r\t@\/\_\(\)]/","",$outtext);
            return $outtext;
        }

        private function read_docx(){

            $striped_content = '';
            $content = '';

            $zip = zip_open($this->filename);

            if (!$zip || is_numeric($zip)) return false;

            while ($zip_entry = zip_read($zip)) {

                if (zip_entry_open($zip, $zip_entry) == FALSE) continue;

                if (zip_entry_name($zip_entry) != "word/document.xml") continue;

                $content .= zip_entry_read($zip_entry, zip_entry_filesize($zip_entry));

                zip_entry_close($zip_entry);
            }// end while

            zip_close($zip);

            $content = str_replace('</w:r></w:p></w:tc><w:tc>', " ", $content);
            $content = str_replace('</w:r></w:p>', "\r\n", $content);
            $striped_content = strip_tags($content);

            return $striped_content;
        }

        public function convertToText() {

            if(isset($this->filename) && !file_exists($this->filename)) {
                return "File Not exists";
            }

            $fileArray = pathinfo($this->filename);
            $file_ext  = $fileArray['extension'];
            echo $file_ext;
            if($ext == "doc" || $ext == "docx" || $ext == "xlsx" || $ext == "pptx")
            {
                if($file_ext == "doc") {
                    return $this->read_doc();
                } elseif($file_ext == "docx") {
                    return $this->read_docx();
                } elseif($file_ext == "xlsx") {
                    return $this->xlsx_to_text();
                }elseif($file_ext == "pptx") {
                    return $this->pptx_to_text();
                }
            } else {
                return "Invalid File Type";
            }
        }

    }
    //calling class to scrape text from file
    //echo $attachment['name'] . "<br />";
    $filenames = file_get_contents('../api/attachmentCV/' . $attachment['name']);
    //echo $filename;
    $docObj = new DocxConversion($filenames);
    //converting string to text
    $docText= $docObj->convertToText();
    echo $docText;
```

Comment: Try echoing out the path and seeing if it actually is right, AND going from ROOT to the file

Comment: I just tried that, the directory is correct as file_get_contents() is not empty and I have echo'd it out and I can see that it is the correct directory. I am just lost as to why it won't open it.

Comment: check the permissions on the file

Comment: Permissions are fine, I even got my hosting provider to check for me, now do to some serious debugging, I am sure I will work it out eventually. Any more suggestions are welcome.

Comment: Have you seen this https://lodge.statamic.com/questions/1913-file-exists-expects-parameter-1-to-be-a- ? In that case it appears the issue could be related to the fact that there's no `default_charset` in the php settings. Have you tried calling `phpinfo()` to see if anything shows up there?

Comment: Yeah I have compared the php_info on both my local server and my hosted one, they are both UTF-8 encoding, I am going to have another look today to see if I can figure it out.